# Read one row per time / only specific column and create object

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I using Apache poi to import an .xlsx file that I have in my desktop area.

With the below code I can read the hole sheet that I want.

But I want to read only one line per time and only specific columns per line (for example I want only column A, F and G from the first line and save it as object, then the same for the second line, third line etc )

How can I do it?

```
public class main {
        public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
            InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("C:/User/Desktop/test.xlsx");
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead);

            XSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            XSSFRow row;
            XSSFCell cell;

            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();


            while (rows.hasNext())
            {
                row=(XSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                while (cells.hasNext())
                {
                    cell=(XSSFCell) cells.next();

                    if (cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
                    {
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
                    }
                    else if(cell.getCellType() == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
                    {
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator)? And all of it? What happens when you do? (Hint - the answer you need is in the docs!)

Answer (score 2):

A specific row can be retrieved from the `Sheet` object using

```
Sheet.getRow(index)
```

Where `index` is a zero based row number. That is, to read row 1, you must get the row at index zero, row 2 is at index 1 and so on. Similarly a specific cell can be retrieved from it's `Row` object using

```
Row.getCell(index)
```

Once again index is a zero based cell number where cell column A is at index 0, column B is at index 1 and so on. Therefore to retrieve the Cell at B2, you could use

```
Cell cell = Sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
```